# Преобразование и вставка данных в DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Интересует, как без использования циклов можно преобразовать и загрузить данные из `func1` и `func2` в `df`, чтобы в результате получить DataFrame со структурой указанной в "Ожидаемый результат"?

В качестве примера приведены две функции, но в реальной задаче кол-во функций может быть неограниченным. Кол-во ключей в справочнике `statistics` не фиксированно. Ключи из данного справочника должны преобразованы в название столбцов в результирующем DataFrame. Значения для пропущенных ключей должны быть заполнены нулями.

```
import pandas as pd

def func1():
    rule = "rule1"
    count = 10
    statistics = pd.Series({0: 13, 2: 15, 3:10})
    return {"rule":rule, "count":count, "s":statistics}

def func2():
    rule = "rule2"
    count = 15
    statistics = pd.Series({0: 17, 1: 18, 3:15, 4: 1})
    return {"rule":rule, "count":count, "s":statistics}

print("Текущие данные")
r1 = pd.DataFrame(func1())
r2 = pd.DataFrame(func2())
print(r1.append(r2))

#####################################

df = pd.DataFrame(
        [
            ["rule1", 10, 13, 0, 15, 10, 0], 
            ["rule2", 15, 17, 18, 0, 15, 1] 
        ], 
        columns = ["rule" , "count", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4"])

print("Ожидаемый результат")
print(df)
```

Результат вывода в консоли:

```
Текущие данные
    rule  count   s
0  rule1     10  13
2  rule1     10  15
3  rule1     10  10
0  rule2     15  17
1  rule2     15  18
3  rule2     15  15
4  rule2     15   1
Ожидаемый результат
    rule  count   0   1   2   3  4
0  rule1     10  13   0  15  10  0
1  rule2     15  17  18   0  15  1
```

Comment: А как ожидаемый результат бьется с данными? Опишите алгоритм его формирования, хотя бы вручную.

Comment: Индекс "текущих данных" -> Соотвествует названию столбцов в конечной таблице. Значение для каждого индекса исходной таблицы в соотвествующий столбец конечной таблицы. Что касается rule и count - там все очевидно.

Comment: Можно занести результаты работы функций в список. [r1, r2]

Comment: Не совсем понял. У меня конечная таблица должна состоять из двух строк

Comment: А как быть с тем, что количество функций неограниченно? Т е. У всех либо rule1 либо rule2?

Comment: на каждую функцию свой уникальных идентификатор rule[N]

Comment: statistics.to_frame().T - вот эта помогает преобразовать переменную statistics из серии в DataFrame. Вопрос как объеденить два фреймы у которых названия столбцов отличаются - concat вроде должен помочь.

Comment: Тогда не получится 2 строки.

Comment: s = statistics.to_frame().T
    s["rule"] = rule
    s["count"] = count
    return s

Comment: каждая функция возвращает DF - с одной строкой, но разным числом столбцов. Как их объеденить ? concat не помог

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходный DataFrame:

```
df = pd.concat(map(pd.DataFrame, [func1(), func2()]))
```

получилось:

```
In [23]: df
Out[23]:
    rule  count   s
0  rule1     10  13
2  rule1     10  15
3  rule1     10  10
0  rule2     15  17
1  rule2     15  18
3  rule2     15  15
4  rule2     15   1
```

Решение:

```
res = (df
       .reset_index()
       .pivot_table(index=["rule", "count"], columns="index", values="s", fill_value=0)
       .reset_index())
```

Результат:

```
In [29]: res
Out[29]:
index   rule  count   0   1   2   3  4
0      rule1     10  13   0  15  10  0
1      rule2     15  17  18   0  15  1
```

Comment: спасибо за красивое и простое решение!